# Is there a way to install Chrome/Chromium in a sandboxed environment from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, android, chromium, google

I'm convinced that when Firefox and Chrome/Chromium are installed together on the same Ubuntu system, that Chrome/Chromium does something to make Firefox slower and less reliable.

Whenever I install Chrome/Chromium on an Ubuntu system, the system always gets really slow about a month later. I have a lot of Ubuntu systems and this happens **all the time**, for the past two years at least, literally.

When I install both Firefox and Chrome/Chromium, the most annoying things happen. It works for a few days, then Firefox is ridiculously slow to start. One of my machines it took almost 10 minutes just to load Firefox, whereas with Chrome/Chromium it was instantaneous.

I really prefer Firefox because it doesn't have any of this sketchy BS added to it. But I need Chrome/Chromium to be able to debug a webview inside my android application. So, is there a way to install Chrome/Chromium inside a sandboxed environment, which can still use USB, without breaking Firefox?

(Are there any alternative softwares to Google's browsers for debugging Android webviews, that don't force me to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 a month after installing them?)

Comment: @steve antwan https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko/FAQ states Firefox uses their own Gecko engine, with an option to use their new Quantum engine. Unable to find any assertion Firefox uses Chromium.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was confused by Brave and also an article i read a while back

Comment: And I (and probably several other people here) have both Firefox and Chrome/Chromium happily co-existing on the same system with neither affecting the other in the way you describe.

Comment: I have had this happen dozens of times so I'm not comprimising here, the question is still valid

Comment: I have had [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/1076412/367990) before, which might be remotely similar to what you describe, but since I fixed it the way I outlined there, I had no problems like this or anything else.

Comment: I dunno man, the second answer there says "Install Chrome against your morals". It's a huge pain to have to reinstall a system

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an extra, very old, Ubuntu laptop that I was already using to play some DRM content using Chrome. I decided to set this up as a permanent android test device that I could access even remotely.

In another situation, one might create a docker image with Chrome involved. [This blog post](https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8) goes over the details, but here's a brief outline.

1. Install dependencies from the docker community edition: `sudo apt-get install docker-ce -y; mkdir chrome-local; cd chrome-local;`
2. Inside a file named: "Dockerfile", put:

   ```sh
   FROM ubuntu:trusty

   RUN apt-get update; apt-get clean

   # Add a user for running applications.
   RUN useradd apps
   RUN mkdir -p /home/apps && chown apps:apps /home/apps

   # Install x11vnc.
   RUN apt-get install -y x11vnc

   # Install xvfb.
   RUN apt-get install -y xvfb

   # Install fluxbox.
   RUN apt-get install -y fluxbox

   # Install wget.
   RUN apt-get install -y wget

   # Install wmctrl.
   RUN apt-get install -y wmctrl

   # Set the Chrome repo.
   RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
       && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

   # Install Chrome.
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable

   COPY bootstrap.sh /

   CMD '/bootstrap.sh'
   ```
3. Inside a file named bootstrap.sh, put:

   ```sh
   #!/bin/bash

   # Based on: http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_Fluxbox_GUI_with_x11vnc_and_Xvfb

   readonly G_LOG_I='[INFO]'
   readonly G_LOG_W='[WARN]'
   readonly G_LOG_E='[ERROR]'

   main() {
       launch_xvfb
       launch_window_manager
       run_vnc_server
   }

   launch_xvfb() {
       # Set defaults if the user did not specify envs.
       export DISPLAY=${XVFB_DISPLAY:-:1}
       local screen=${XVFB_SCREEN:-0}
       local resolution=${XVFB_RESOLUTION:-1280x1024x24}
       local timeout=${XVFB_TIMEOUT:-5}

       # Start and wait for either Xvfb to be fully up or we hit the timeout.
       Xvfb ${DISPLAY} -screen ${screen} ${resolution} &
       local loopCount=0
       until xdpyinfo -display ${DISPLAY} > /dev/null 2>&1
       do
           loopCount=$((loopCount+1))
           sleep 1
           if [ ${loopCount} -gt ${timeout} ]
           then
               echo "${G_LOG_E} xvfb failed to start."
               exit 1
           fi
       done
   }

   launch_window_manager() {
       local timeout=${XVFB_TIMEOUT:-5}

       # Start and wait for either fluxbox to be fully up or we hit the timeout.
       fluxbox &
       local loopCount=0
       until wmctrl -m > /dev/null 2>&1
       do
           loopCount=$((loopCount+1))
           sleep 1
           if [ ${loopCount} -gt ${timeout} ]
           then
               echo "${G_LOG_E} fluxbox failed to start."
               exit 1
           fi
       done
   }

   run_vnc_server() {
       local passwordArgument='-nopw'

       if [ -n "${VNC_SERVER_PASSWORD}" ]
       then
           local passwordFilePath="${HOME}/x11vnc.pass"
           if ! x11vnc -storepasswd "${VNC_SERVER_PASSWORD}" "${passwordFilePath}"
           then
               echo "${G_LOG_E} Failed to store x11vnc password."
               exit 1
           fi
           passwordArgument=-"-rfbauth ${passwordFilePath}"
           echo "${G_LOG_I} The VNC server will ask for a password."
       else
           echo "${G_LOG_W} The VNC server will NOT ask for a password."
       fi

       x11vnc -display ${DISPLAY} -forever ${passwordArgument} &
       wait $!
   }

   control_c() {
       echo ""
       exit
   }

   trap control_c SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP

   main

   exit
   ```
4. Build the docker image: `chmod +x boostrap.sh; docker build -t local/chrome:0.0.1 .` - Note the trailing `.`! This builds the image in the Dockerfile above and gives it a name called `local/chrome:0.0.1`.
5. Run the docker image with: `docker run -p 5900:5900 -e VNC_SERVER_PASSWORD=password --user apps --privileged local/chrome:0.0.1`
6. Use a VNC client to connect to port `5900` which holds your docker image